# Как сделать плавную прокрутку на jQuery на сайте Joomla

Tags: jquery, joomla, javascript

Здравствуйте!
Есть сайт: [link text](http://www.vector-mp.com.ua/)

Необходимо реализовать плавную прокрутку по якорям. Меню сделано с помощью обычного модуля html-код. В каждом пункте меню прописаны ссылки на якори в статье. 
Использую следующий код для плавной прокрутки:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.topLink").click(function() {
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: $($(this).attr("href")).offset().top + "px"
        }, {
            duration: 500
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Но почему-то не работает, хотя библиотеку подключил к шаблону. Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно это сделать? Впервые с этим сталкиваюсь просто

Всем спасибо за ответы, всё получилось.

Comment: Извините за оффтоп, а на кой черт там Joomla?

Одна страница ведь. вручную чтоль жалко сверстать ?)

Comment: Это уже до меня было сделано, я просто выполняю доработки по сайту. И вот осталось сделать прокрутку, и никак не выходит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скрипт неработает, так как на странице нет элементов с тем id, который прописан в цели ссылки. Соответственно `$($(this).attr("href"))` возвращает 0 элементов. На странице все якори на которые Вы ссылаетесь измените с:

```
<a name="[имя]" id="vector">&nbsp;</a>
```

на

```
<a id="[имя]">&nbsp;</a>
```

Небольшая демонстрация: http://jsfiddle.net/HACk9/1/

PS: По факту у Вас сейчас на странице масса элементов с одинаковым id "vector", что довольно плохо.

Comment: Ага, то есть просто вместо  самого якоря прописать id?И ещё такой вопрос, будут ли таким образом работать пункты меню, которые ссылаются на якори?

Comment: В якоре замените атрибут name на id. Будут работать как обычные ссылки, так и ссылки с перехватом клика и плавной прокруткой. Рекомендую посмотреть: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp